# Error : EXC_Bad_Access while accessing a retainCount of an Object

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

In header file .h

```
@interface MemoryAppDelegate:NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
Class1 *class1_obj;
}
```

In Implementation file .m

```
@implementation Memory : (UIApplication*) application
{
 NSLog(@"Retain Count of class1_obj %d",[class1_obj retainCount]); //ouput retainCount is 0
 Class2 *class2_obj;
 NSLog(@"Retain Count of class2_obj %d",[class2_obj retainCount]); // gives EXC_Bad_Access error
```

As in the above code, when I declare a object in header file and try to access its retain count is gives me 0. But if I declare the object in implementation file and access its retainCount it throws Bad_Access.
Kindly can you say why this error occurs?

Comment: Thanks all, now i am clear why this error occurs.

Comment: Note that retainCount can never return zero.

Comment: @bbum, I believe calling it on a nil object does return 0 (see the answer of frenetisch applaudierend).

Comment: Yes I tried it and the answer is correct by frenetisch, when u nil a object, the retain count shows as zero.

Comment: @MiRAGe That is incorrect;  no method is executed.  `objc_msgSend()` short circuits messages-to-nil within the first 2 or 3 instructions.  That it is zero is a side-effect (that can be disabled, btw) of the runtime and has nothing to do with the implementation of `retainCount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all : You should not access any object's `retaincount` in your application.

To answer your question :

- `object1` is an instance variable, it points to `nil` when not initiated. When you send a message to `nil`, it returns `nil` (here, 0).
- `object2` is a pointer that has not been set to anything, not even `nil`, so it may be pointing to anything. Here, it points to a non-existing object, so it crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you do all this, but this code:

```
 Class2 *class2_obj;
 NSLog(@"Retain Count of class2_obj %d",[class2_obj retainCount]); // gives EXC_Bad_Access error
```

Only creates a pointer to a certain type of object, it doesn't actually create an instance. So accessing it and asking its retainCount (which you shouldn't do in the first place), will result in a valid crash. Because it is not a valid object (yet). Try initializing it first.

UPDATE:
if you insist on doing this, here is something that might work

```
Class2 *class2_obj = [[Class2 alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Retain Count of class2_obj %d",[class2_obj retainCount]); // gives retain count of 1
[class2_obj release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you declare it in the class as an instance variable, it's automatically initialized with `nil`. And `[nil retainCount]` returns again `nil` which is `0` when printed as integer (`%d`)

But a variable which is declared locally is not initialized and such a pointer points just somewhere, most likely to a block of memory which is not allocated. And since trying to access a memory location which is not allocated results in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` you experience the error you described.